# refresh a page and should post data each time it refreshes?

Tags: php, curl

i want that this code refreshes itself & post the data to sendsms.php but should not redirect and remain on this page.tus each time it refreshes it download new data and post to sendsms.php. plz suggest me any idea?

```
  <?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
     $sec = "15";
     header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
    $url=$_REQUEST['url'];
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $html= curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

    //parsing begins here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

    //get and display what you need:
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $first = current(explode("|", $title));

    $to="888888888";
    header('Location: sendsms.php?to=' .$to .'&sms=' .$first);

    ?>
```

Comment: use cURL to post data on  sendsms.php

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running it through crontab.

You have two options, the first being the better:

1. Run the file directly on the server as a shell script.
2. Use curl or wget to access the file on a web server.

The first scenario would look something like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /my/home/path/script.php
```

The second scenario would be similar:

```
* * * * * curl http://example.com/path/to/file/script.php
```

This is not exactly what you asked for, of course. If you wanted this page to simply sit in a web browser and reload every n seconds, you could use JavaScript and some jQuery AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timer = setInterval(function () {
  $.post('/sendsms.php', { data: yourdata }, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}, 15000);
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Any standard refresh will not re-post the data. Depending on browser it'll either make a usual GET request or the browser will ask you to confirm the POST data re-submit.

You can do what you need by creating a form in html and adding all variables you need in POST data into that form as < input type="hidden" >. Then you can submit that form using javascript (after the required delay - 15 seconds in your case).